# UWP Changing style of AppBarButton breaks the dynamic overflow's automatic styling

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, commandbar

Trying to use the new IsDynamicOverflowEnabled property on the CommandBar and I've run into a styling issue with the Overflow. Issue is as follows, when the AppBarButton's Style is not overridden and drops off to the Overflow area, the highlight of the AppBarButton stretches across the entire width of the Popup and its hover/hit detection is also the entire width of the Popup.

When it's Style is overridden the highlight only covers the area of the text (in this case home) and its hover/hit detection are only over this area, even if the overriding Style is exactly the same as the one in the generic.xaml.

I notice when inspecting the properties at Runtime that the ones that aren't being overridden are being applied another style from the TargetType - FrameworkElement.

From looking through the generic.xaml, the only place I can see this sort of change to a style is in the CommandBarOverflowPresenter (see below)

```
<CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN" />
  </Style>
</CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle>
```

To remove all of the other noise from the app I'm working on, I created a new project with just a CommandBar on the main page and the necessary buttons and text needed to replicate my issue. Below is the mainpage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="AppBarButton">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}" />
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
              Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
              Value="Left" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
              Value="Top" />
      <Setter Property="FontFamily"
              Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight"
              Value="Normal" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="68" />
      <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
              Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction"
              Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
            <Grid x:Name="Root"
                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                  MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
              <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle"
                       TargetType="AppBarButton">
                  <Setter Property="Width"
                          Value="NaN" />
                </Style>
              </Grid.Resources>
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="12,14,0,14" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="0" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="1" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Left" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="8,15,12,17" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Collapsed" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="Visible" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="38,0,12,0" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                      <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding"
                              Value="0,11,0,13" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                  </VisualState>
                  <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                      <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding"
                              Value="0,11,0,13" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot"
                    MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                                  Height="20"
                                  Margin="0,14,0,4"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                           FontSize="12"
                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Margin="2,0,2,6" />
              </Grid>
              <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                         Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                         Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                         FontSize="15"
                         FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                         TextAlignment="Left"
                         TextTrimming="Clip"
                         TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="12,0,12,0"
                         Padding="0,5,0,7"
                         Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>

  <Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="True">
      <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Text to force the buttons to drop off at some point when the screen is resized" />
      </CommandBar.Content>
      <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Label="Edit"
                      Icon="Edit" />
        <AppBarButton Label="People"
                      Icon="People" />
        <AppBarButton Label="Really long text should should make overflow wider"
                      Icon="Highlight" />
        <AppBarButton Label="Home"
                      Icon="Home"
                      Style="{StaticResource Style}" />
      </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
  </Page.TopAppBar>
</Page>
```

As you can see I have 1 CommandBar, 1 TextBlock in the content of the CommandBar and 4 AppBarButtons in the CommandBar's PrimaryCommands. Only 1 of the AppBarButtons Styles is overridden (the Home one) and the Style which it is overridden with is grabbed directly from the generic.xaml from this location - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic

Why does this happen? And is there any known workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've known, while an [AppBarButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) is added into [SecondaryCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.secondarycommands.aspx), it will display in Popup. And if you check with [Live Visual Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) in Visual Studio, you will find the `AppBarButton` is added in to a [CommandBarOverflowPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbaroverflowpresenter.aspx) named "SecondaryItemsControl".
[image]

The style you've found under `CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle` is used to reset `AppBarButton`'s `Width` and `HorizontalAlignment` property as by default `AppBarButton`'s `Width` is `68` and `HorizontalAlignment` is set to `Left` and if we use the default style, the `AppBarButton` can't take the whole width of the Popup.

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="Width" Value="68"/>
```

However, the style under `CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle` only applies on the `AppBarButton` with implicit styles. If you set the `Style` property of `AppBarButton` explicitly, it will lose its function. And this is the reason why changing style of `AppBarButton` breaks the dynamic overflow's automatic styling.

As a workaround, you can try to change the `Width` and `HorizontalAlignment` property like what under `CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle` and set `MiniWidth` to limit `AppBarButton`'s width.

```
<Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="68" />
    ...
</Style>
```

*PS: This workaround may be not suitable for all scenarios, especially when the `AppBarButton` has a long `Label`. You may need to determine whether to use it according to your scenario.*

**Update:**

> Your answer raises another question, why can only implicit styles inherit this `CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle`?

This is related to [Lookup behavior for XAML resource references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#lookup-behavior-for-xaml-resource-references). You can think that `Style`s have been set explicitly have the highest priority. Once you set the `Style` property, the XAML system will not look for other styles.

Ref [ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references):

> The XAML framework also looks for implicit style resources (those which use **[TargetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.style.targettype.aspx)** rather than [x:Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt204787) or [x:Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt204788)) when it decides which style & template to use for a control that hasn't set the [**Style**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208743) and [**ContentTemplate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209369) or [**ItemTemplate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242830) properties.

So once you set `Style` for `AppBarButton`, the implicit style under `CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle` won't work.

Following is a simple sample that demonstrates this behavior.

```
<Page ...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListViewItem Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}">1</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem Background="Blue">2</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>3</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>4</ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, for the first item, as I've set the `Style` property explicitly, it won't use the style under `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`. For the second item, as I didn't set the `Style` property, it will use the implicit style under `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`, however the property that has been set explicitly has a higher priority. So this item's foreground is white but its background is blue. And for the third and fourth item, as they use the default style which has the lowest priority, so the implicit style under `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` will be used instead of the default style.

Comment: Thanks for the info and potential workaround, I don't think it will work for my scenario as I do have long(ish) labels. 

Your answer raises another question, why can only implicit styles inherit this `CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle`?
It seems more like a bug to me that this `Style` would no longer be inherited because **I** had overridden a `Style` not linked to it.

Comment: @jsmyth886 This is not a bug. It's expected and intentional. The problem here is related to the  Lookup behavior for XAML resource references. Please check my updated answer. And I'm afraid there is no "one size fits all" solution. You have to balance between dynamic overflow function and custom style and try to find the best solution for your scenario.

Comment: @jsmyth886 I don't know what you actual scenario is. But as I've explained, this problem occurs when we set the `Style` property explicitly. You can try to set your custom style as a implicit style that applies to all s and set properties for different `AppBarButton`.

Comment: @jay-zuo-msft thanks again for the detailed information. Would a possible workaround be to extend the `AppBarButton` create a default (implicit) style, whihc has exactly what I need, and apply it to all the `AppBarButton`'s in my `CommandBar`. I'll also mark your answer as correct since it has helped me understand much more about the platform in general